# Excel AVERAGEIF value > 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to calculate the average of multiple cells and I want to exclude values = 0.

The cells are not sequential so I cannot use AVERAGEIF(A1:A10, ">0")

I need to individually select the cells however, I want to copy the formula across multiple columns so do not want exclude any (manually)

How do I do this?

An example of the data is seen here:
[image]

I want to calculate an average of all rows for Tier 1, Tier 2 and CBD (excluding 0)

Comment: Values in different columns, or same column?

Comment: see image and edit

Comment: For future reference this question is better asked at Super User  - it is not programming.

Comment: what version of excel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AVERAGEIFS, which lets you select criteria for averaging:

=AVERAGEIFS(A3:Z3,A$2:Z$2,"=Tier 1",A3:Z3,">0")

Then, when specifying the range for the criteria, be sure  you lock the row number. (A$2:Z$2, rather than simply specifying the range as A2:Z2.) Otherwise, when you propogate down for subsequent row averages, Excel will (correctly) attempt to populate it as A3:Z3 and throw out a DIV/0 error.

Comment: This is going to be difficult for the highlighted cells, as you would need a criteria where several cities are checked to decide if they should be considered in the range

Comment: I like this for the Tier 1 & Tier 2 but it still leaves out the CBD suburbs. I might have to do CBD differently

Comment: I have just changed the heading to CBD and use an alternate method of calculating the cell values hence making this solution work perfectly.

Comment: If CBD is all those that aren't Tier 1 or Tier 2 you could try this version with a "wildcard" leaving headers unaltered `=AVERAGEIFS(A3:Z3,A$2:Z$2,"<>Tier*",A3:Z3,">0")`

Answer (score 2):

In any version., you can use this type of formula to AVERAGE non-contiguous cells without zeroes (assumes positive values only)

`=SUM(A2,F3,Z5)/MAX(1,INDEX(FREQUENCY((A2,F3,Z5),0),2))`

where A2, F3 and Z5 are the cells to average

Formula returns zero if there are no non-zero values

You can name your range of non-contiguous cells, if you wish, and then use

`=SUM(Range1)/MAX(1,INDEX(FREQUENCY(Range1,0),2))`

Answer (score 1):

This looks horrible, and also requires Excel 2007 or greater:

```
=SUM(A2,D2,G2,J2,M2,P2,S2,V2)/COUNTIFS(A2,"<>0",D2,"<>0",G2,"<>0",J2,"<>0",M2,"<>0",P2,"<>0",S2,"<>0",V2,"<>0")
```

but it will average the selected cells (no criteria needed for `SUM` as adding zero or not doesn't alter the total.

Comment: I tried this but was getting errors so I gave up. I think it is the only solution that will work .